# scikit-learn でエラー:'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

Pythonで `X_train = X_train.reshape(1, -1)` を実行したところエラーが起きてしまいまして。初心者で質問も多いですが、指摘よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv

csvfile = open('BioAsseT practice data5.csv')
df = pd.read_csv("BioAsseT practice data5.csv")
X= df.external
y= df.total
print(X.shape, y.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
X_train, X_val,  y_train, y_val, =train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.5, random_state=1)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X_train = X_train.reshape(1, -1)
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ac8a18039b04> in <module>
----> 1 X_train = X_train.reshape(1, -1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: エラーメッセージ「AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'」の通りかと思いますが、エラーの発生したコード「X_train = X_train.reshape(1, -1)」では何をしたかったのでしょうか？どういうデータをどういう形にしたいのか書かれると回答しやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: なるほどです。基礎がまだなっていないのでどのファイルに変形すればいいか勉強し確認します。